# Passing data between nodes. How to keep them clean?

Tags: java, architecture, software-design

My application "nodes" are organised as tree structure with parent and children:

```
 A---------B---------C---------D---------E
                               \---------F
```

A is the top ancestor while E and F are the bottom descendent. The execution flow is from ascendant side to the descendent side.

Every single node accepts certain types of data that they need to process. So in the design decision, the data that nodes can receive is isolated to each other.

Now a problem appears, let's say node E and F need a certain type of data, but it is only available at C node. So I need a mechanism to transfer that data from C node, all the way to E and F nodes.

Solution 1: Allow descendent nodes access to data of their ancestor nodes. So I can just add that data to C node, and get it out from E and F nodes. What I don't like about this solution is that, all intermediated nodes(including C and D), will contain some data that they don't actually need. To me it sounds like a problem in managing the application in the future.

Solution 2: Introduce a temporary storage class, that can be used in C to store data, and read out from E and F nodes (bring data to where it is needed). This solution, to me, somehow sounds a bit unclean, and adds complexity to the application.

So it you were me, which solution would you go for, or a different solution that I can't see?

Since I'm new to software design, any comment, suggestion from you are very welcomed.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you add some code to make it clear?

Comment: I can see a message bus being of help here.

Answer (score 0):

nodes should be independent from each other and it should not have any knowledge the order and the layout of the nodes.

class which connects the node should have the knowledge to propagate data between nodes.
so better option is to introduce a `DataConnector`
CtoEDataConnector will get a notification once C is done its process.once it got the notification it will access the data Container of C and extract data and will be populated to node E.

that means, DataConnectors should be added at the time nodes are connected to each other.